# How to fix AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid. error

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, web-config

I am loading a project from Visual Studio, but when the browser opens it up, I get this error:

```
Sign in
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.

Request Id: 3f0f91e4-d199-4d50-82bb-081ea2612f00
Correlation Id: b03fd8b7-b92c-43c3-b289-3c3d9b64e743
Timestamp: 2020-09-30T00:19:02Z
Message: AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\
```

Where could this issue be in? Web.config file? Access token?

Comment: Are you using the auth code flow?If so，check your 'code'.

Comment: The issue is while your acquire the access token. Can you share more details like which authentication type and code/library you are using to login.?

Comment: Hi @fibonaccilinguine are you still looking for any help of this.?